# MySQL 5: Does it matter what order my GROUP BY fields are in?

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by

Peeps,

I have a few aggregate/calculated fields in my MySQL query. My GROUP BY clause is dynamically generated, depending on what options a user selects in a web form. Curious if the order of fields listed in the GROUP BY clause can have any impact on the calculations (things like SUMs, AVERAGEs, etc)

Thanks!

Comment: When you tried two different versions, what did you measure?

Comment: Make sure to checkout the [mysql-optimization-guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-optimization.html) for optimization rules on group by. As one of the answers below states order does effect the index lookup speed in mysql.

Answer (score 5):

It WILL matter if you are using `WITH ROLLUP`, otherwise, it should not.

Comment: See below for why this can matter a lot for index usage.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I just tried it for a problem I had, and it turns out it matters a great deal for index usage.

Let's say we have a secondary index on a `Customers` table with two columns (City, State) -- and they are specified in this order in the index.

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Customers GROUP BY City, State
EXPLAIN shows that it uses the index.

But...

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Customers GROUP BY State, City
EXPLAIN shows that it does not use the index.

This is on MySQL 5.1 with an InnoDB table.

Comment: Please elaborate: you say it does matter, but you do not say how. You _imply_ it is a performance impact, but are the _results_ any different? I think they are not (unless you use `WITH ROLLUP`, as noted by @gahooa).

Answer (score 1):

no, that shouldn't matter