# Does the order of columns matter in a group by clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

If I have two columns, one with very high cardinality and one with very low cardinality (unique # of values), does it matter in which order I group by?

Here's an example:

```
select 
     dimensionName, 
     dimensionCategory, 
     sum(someFact)
from SomeFact f
join SomeDim d on f.dimensionKey = d.dimensionKey
group by 
    d.dimensionName,  -- large number of unique values
    d.dimensionCategory -- small number of unique values
```

Are there situations where it matters?

Comment: See related post as well: [MYSQL5 order of group by...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095645/mysql-5-does-it-matter-what-order-my-group-by-fields-are-in)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

No, the order doesn't matter for the GROUP BY clause.

MySQL and SQLite are the only databases I'm aware of that allow you to select columns which are omitted from the group by (non-standard, not portable) but the order doesn't matter there either.

Comment: Minor remark: "Non-standard" depends in some cases on the standard version. Since 1999 or so, it is explicitely allowed to use functional dependent column names in the SELECT clause, since each of their values may be different from every column in the GROUP BY, but never changes within the group.

Answer (score 31):

SQL is declarative.

In this case, you have told the optimiser how you want the data grouped and it works out how to do it.

It won't evaluate line by line (procedural) and look at one column first

The main place column order matters is for indexes. `col1, col2` is not the same as `col2, col1`. At all.

Comment: It also matters for ORDER BY.

Answer (score 15):

Since this has not been mentioned here. The answers above are correct i.e. the order of the columns after the "group by" clause will not affect the **correctness** of the query (i.e. the sum amount).

However, the order of the rows being retrieved will vary based on the order of the columns specified after the "group by" clause. For example consider Table `A` with the following rows:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
1   xyz 100
2   abc 200
3   xyz 300
3   xyz 400
```

`SELECT *, SUM(Col3) FROM A GROUP BY  Col2, Col1` will retrieve rows ordered by the `Col2` in ascending order.

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 sum(Col3)
2   abc 200 200
1   xyz 100 100
3   xyz 300 700
```

Now change the ordering of column in group by to `Col1, Col2`. The retrieved rows are ordered asc by `Col1`.

i.e. `select *, sum(Col3) from A group by  Col1, Col2`

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 sum(Col3)
1   xyz 100 100
2   abc 200 200
3   xyz 300 700
```

Note: The the summation amount (i.e. the correctness of the query) remains exactly the same.

Comment: But, unless an "ORDER BY" is used, the row order of select results is undefined anyway, isn't it? So you should never rely on any particular order of rows, even if not using GROUP BY at all.

Comment: Agreeing to @avl_sweden, I think the response should at the very least indicate that this behaviour is implementation-specific. There is no guarantee that a newer (or even the same) version of SQL server won't produce a different ordering.

Answer (score 12):

There's a legacy, non-standard feature of Microsoft SQL Server called ROLLUP. ROLLUP is an extension to the GROUP BY syntax and when it is used the order of the GROUP BY columns determines which columns should be grouped in the result. ROLLUP is deprecated however. The standard SQL alternative is to use grouping sets, which is supported by SQL Server 2008 and later versions.

Answer (score 1):

If I have two columns, one with very high cardinality and one with very low cardinality (unique # of values), does it matter in which order I group by?

**Query-1**

```
SELECT spec_id, catid, spec_display_value, COUNT(*) AS cnt  FROM tbl_product_spec 
GROUP BY spec_id, catid, spec_display_value ;
```

**Query-2**

```
SELECT spec_id, catid, spec_display_value, COUNT(*) AS cnt  FROM tbl_product_spec FORCE INDEX(idx_comp_spec_cnt)
GROUP BY catid, spec_id,spec_display_value;
```

Both are equal , order doesn't work in group by clause.